# cvxpy Repeatedly solving a problem get the “”Problem is unbounded“”

Tags: python, cvxpy

I used CVXPY to solve a planning problem, which requires running the same problem multiple times with inputting different parameters. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgUCl.jpg)I obtained the result in the form of DCP, which is "Problem is unbound". If the same data replaced by a constant “c” [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDFtD.jpg)directly passed in, the correct result can be obtained。the “x” is x = cp.Variable(matrix_len, integer=True) 。

```
c= np.array([1,2,3,6])
matrix_len = len(c)
gmma = cp.Parameter(matrix_len,nonneg=True)
gmma.value = [1,2,3,6]
# c = np.array([1.42900, 1.45900, 1.31800, 1.27500, 1.26300, 1.24900, 1.25900])
constraint_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_len,matrix_len),dtype='int')
# # 定义约束矩阵      /将矩阵对角线一侧设置为0
for i in range(len(constraint_matrix)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        constraint_matrix[i][j] = -1
# 生成tmp矩阵
mid_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_len,matrix_len),dtype='int')+1

# # 定义约束矩阵      /将矩阵对角线一侧设置为0
for i in range(matrix_len):
    for j in range(i):
        mid_matrix[j][i] = 0

cs_matrix2 = mid_matrix * gmma

# 生成对角矩阵
# d = np.diag(np.zeros(5))
b = np.zeros((matrix_len),dtype='int')+5685    # 定义约束条件的右边向量
c = np.zeros((matrix_len),dtype='int')
x = cp.Variable(matrix_len, integer=True)  # 定义两个整数决策变量
obj = cp.Minimize(gmma * x)  # 构造目标函数
cons = [constraint_matrix * x <= b,cs_matrix2 * x <= c]  # 构造约束条件
prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)  # 构建问题模型
prob.solve(solver='CBC', verbose=True )  # 求解问题
print("最优值为:", prob.value+c[0]*5685)
```

## the second one using the common method

```
c= np.array([1,2,3,6])
matrix_len = len(c)
# c = np.array([1.42900, 1.45900, 1.31800, 1.27500, 1.26300, 1.24900, 1.25900])
constraint_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_len,matrix_len),dtype='int')
# # 定义约束矩阵      /将矩阵对角线一侧设置为0
for i in range(len(constraint_matrix)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        constraint_matrix[i][j] = -1
# 生成tmp矩阵
mid_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_len,1),dtype='int')+1
cs_matrix2 = mid_matrix*c
# # 定义约束矩阵      /将矩阵对角线一侧设置为0
for i in range(len(cs_matrix2)):
    for j in range(i):
        cs_matrix2[j][i] = 0

# 生成对角矩阵
# d = np.diag(np.zeros(5))
b = np.zeros((matrix_len),dtype='int')+5685    # 定义约束条件的右边向量
c = np.zeros((matrix_len),dtype='int')
x = cp.Variable(matrix_len, integer=True)  # 定义两个整数决策变量
obj = cp.Minimize(c * x)  # 构造目标函数
cons = [constraint_matrix * x <= b,cs_matrix2 * x <= c]  # 构造约束条件
prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)  # 构建问题模型
prob.solve(solver='CBC', verbose=True )  # 求解问题
print("最优值为:", prob.value+c[0]*5685)
```

using the same solver and data produce different results ，i dont know why

Comment: Please port the code as a text, and not an images

Comment: Edit in your post not in comment.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this